# Les verbes ou tournures qui déclenchent le subjonctif

Tags: verbes, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

De *Advanced French Grammar* de V. Mazet :

> Page 59 : Verbs introducing the subjunctive ... express wish and preference, emotion and feeling, doubt or possibility, neccessity, and so on, as long as the main verb expresses subjectivity...
>
> Page 69 : You're familiar with verbs expressing desire and want, ..., emotions. We'll focus on less common, and sometimes confusing, trigger expressions.  Here are several ... :
>
> ♦ avoir de la chance que, ce n'est pas la peine que, comment se fait-il .... que ?, comprendre que, être d'accord pour que, il arrive que, il est temps que, il ne sert à rien que, il n'est pas question que, il n'y a aucune chance que, [ personne n'aurait pensé que ] **que** ...
>
> Page 71 :  Some ▲ common trigger expressions look like expressions that ▼ don't introduce the subjunctive .
>
> ▲ douter que vs ▼ se douter que,
> ▲ il est heureux que vs ▼ heureusement que,
> ▲ il semble que vs ▼ il me semble que,
> ▲ souhaiter que vs ▼ espérer que

Mes questions :

1. Comment les verbes dans ♦ satisfont les critères du subjonctif ? Ils ne me paraissent ni aborder ni désigner la subjectivité.
2. Comment rationaliser ou détailler les combinaisons de la p. 71 ? Elles m'ébahissent car elles ont des sens proches.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la deuxième partie de ta question, la seule réponse qui me semble raisonnable c'est que c'est ainsi. Certaines constructions entraînent le subjonctif et d'autres non. Il n'y a rien à comprendre : c'est ainsi et il faut l'apprendre.

Answer (score 1):

L'emploi du subjonctif est déterminé pas seulement par le sens des verbes employés mais par ce que le locuteur veut exprimer et voir ça uniquement en terme de subjectivité est trop vague ; je dirais que c'est une question d'appréciation de la réalisation ou possibilité de réalisation de l'action de la part du locuteur.

À partir des verbes que tu donnes je justifierais l'emploi du subjonctif ainsi :

**Appréciation**
J'ai de la chance qu'il vienne.
Je comprends que tu sois d'accord.
Il est temps qu'il vienne.
Il n'est pas question que tu viennes.

**Nécessité**
Ce n'est pas la peine qu'il vienne.
Ça ne sert à rien qu'il vienne.

**Possibilité**
Il arrive que je sois d'accord.

**Certitude**
Il n'y a aucune chance qu'il vienne.

**Émotion** (ici étonnement)
Comment se fait-il qu'il vienne ?

Pour les différentes valeurs du subjonctif on pourra voir [cette page](http://www.lefrancaispourtous.com/subjonctif2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

L'usage du subjonctif est probablement une des questions d'usage les plus complexes en français. Comme le remarque Laure, il n'est clairement pas gouverné que par la logique. Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §§898-899, 1127) prend pas moins 20 pages pour en parler et ne couvre même pas tous les cas. Il y a une variation non négligeable dans les deux directions, et je me rappelle avoir lu quelque part que cette variation est dû à une évolution de la sémantique de ce mode, évolution qui ne serait pas encore achevée. Quant aux cas présentés ici…

*Se douter que* et *il me semble que* ont le sens de "croire", "penser", verbes qui ne régissent  normalement pas le subjonctif (ils le font dans les phrases négatives).

*Espérer* ne régit normalement le subjonctif qu'à l'imparfait. Toutefois Grevisse note que s'il régit normalement l’indicatif aux autres temps, le subjonctif est également admis ([quelques exemples ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=52970)).

Il n'est pas difficile de trouver des exemples en ligne où *heureusement que* est suivi d'un subjonctif. Je crois que c'est facile à expliquer dans la mesure où Grevisse associe ce mode à "l'expression de l'émotion" (*heureux que*, qui influence clairement la formation adverbiale, exprime d'ailleurs presque toujours un fait avéré), et bien entendu cette phrase exprime un fort soulagement. Il conclut d'ailleurs à ce sujet (§1126 d 1<sup>o</sup> R10) que "Le subjonctif s'emploie même quand le fait a une pleine réalité, sans doute parce que le sens du support n'implique pas en soit cette réalité." C'est plutôt abscons, mais je crois qu'il veut dire essentiellement que la sémantique passe alors avant la logique.