# Subjonctif ou imparfait/futur simple?

Tags: subjonctif, imparfait, futur-simple

J'ai récemment entendu une native française dire *« Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il était là. »* Est-ce correct ? Sinon, pourquoi pas le subjonctif, car on exprime de l'incertitude ?

J'ai aussi entendu un autre Français dire *« Je ne pense pas que je le verrai demain. »* Et je me demande encore pourquoi pas le subjonctif, car c'est la négation de « je pense que ... » ?

Comment: Ca pourrait être le langage informel ou des cas où le sens de la phrase ne permet pas l'utilisation du sobjonctif. En outre, comme un des mes enseignants de français toujours disait, l'utilisation du sobjonctif depend de la personne, leur niveau d'education, comment parlaient leur parents, etc.

Comment: Non seulement le subjonctif à certains temps n'est pas ou peu utilisé dans la conversation courante, mais son emploi peut aussi se discuter selon ce qu'on veut exprimer (doute, possibilité, vraisemblance...) [Les verbes ou tournures qui déclenchent le subjonctif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/les-verbes-ou-tournures-qui-d%c3%a9clenchent-le-subjonctif)

Comment: @guillaume31 La question posée ici est induite par la présence de la négation das la principale, cas pas traitée dans la question à laquelle tu renvoies.

Comment: @None pourquoi la négation ferait-elle l'objet d'une règle spécifique ? Si tu as des sources là-dessus je suis intéressé. (n'hésite pas à poster une réponse également si tu penses avoir la solution)

Comment: @guillaume31 c'est un cas classique dans les grammaires, [par ex](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/completives-mode.html) : "Certains ver­bes demandant l’in­di­ca­tif amè­nent le sub­jonc­tif dans la com­plé­tive quand ils sont à la for­me né­ga­tive."  Mais ça a déjà dû être traité ici. Oui je prépare une réponse, au moins partielle, 2 cas différents dans cette question.

Comment: @None ta propre réponse a la question que je mets en lien comporte des phrases né­ga­tives, qui ne sont pas mises en avant en tant que telles mais classé­es sous une intention (certitude, appré­ciation)...

Comment: @guillaume31 Exact, mais chaque cas étant spécifique la question me semble justifiée.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avec *être sûr*, une forme affirmative entraîne l'indicatif alors qu'une forme négative entraîne normalement le subjonctif. Au présent :

> Je suis sûre qu'il est là.

> Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il soit là.

L'indicatif serait assez relâché mais s'entend cependant assez souvent :

> Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il est là.

Voir *[La Grande grammaire du français](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gndEEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT2239&lpg=PT2239&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, Anne Abeillé, Danièle Godard, pour plus de détails.

Au passé, la concordance des temps imposerait l'imparfait du subjonctif dans la subordonnée :

> Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il fût là.

mais plus personne ne s'exprime comme ça à l'oral.

En langage soutenu, ce serait :

> Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il ait été là.

et en langage courant :

> Je ne suis pas sûre qu'il était là.

Il n'est d'ailleurs pas exclu que le subjonctif ait été utilisé mais soit passé inaperçu par fusion des deux /e/ successifs (ait é-).

Dans la deuxième phrase, la subordonnée est au futur, temps qui contient par nature toujours une part hypothétique. Il n'existe d'ailleurs pas de subjonctif futur donc l'indicatif est utilisé.

> Je ne pense pas que je le verrai demain.

On aurait pu aussi utiliser l'infinitif car les deux sujets sont identiques :

> Je ne pense pas le voir demain.

Au présent on aurait bien une alternance indicatif/subjonctif :

> Je pense que je le vois/prends.

> Je ne pense pas que je le voie/prenne.

mais l'indicatif est aussi possible :

> Je ne pense pas que je le vois/prends.

ainsi que l'infinitif, probablement beaucoup plus courant :

> Je ne pense pas le voir/prendre.

Comment: En appui: https://books.google.fr/books?id=gndEEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT2239&lpg=PT2239&dq

Comment: c'est la même chose pour le futur simple ?